# Does alum react with zinc?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I want to remove a hardened steel bolt in a block of zinc (there is a through-hole, so I have two sides to work with). I have done this previously with aluminum and steel before, using a solution of alum to loosen the steel bolt.

Will I have as smooth a time using the alum method in the present case, or will the alum react with the zinc?

Comment: Related - but not duplicate - post [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-dissolve-steel-without-affecting-aluminium-alloy).